# Is it possible to use binary search, that recieves letters?

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm trying to use binary search for my program and I have a problem. Now my search function works only with words (so it receives a list of strings and a string, and the output is the string that we try to search).

But is it possible to use binary search that receives a list of strings and a string of letters, and outputs a list that contains all strings, which starts with the letter that was given as input?

Example:

INPUT: `['car', 'var', 'dominicano', 'dominic', 'dancer'], 'd'`

OUTPUT: `['dancer', 'dominic', 'dominicano']`

Here's my binary search function that works only with words in Python:

```
def binary_search(data, key):
    low = 0
    high = len(data)

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low+high) // 2
        try:
            if data[mid] == key:
                return data[mid]
            if data[mid] > key:
                high = mid-1
            else:
                low = mid + 1
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve... Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, of course. Example:

INPUT: (['car', 'var', 'dominicano', 'dominic', 'dancer'], 'd')

OUTPUT: ([ 'dancer', 'dominic', 'dominicano'])

Comment: Please [edit] the question with examples and clarifications

Comment: But binary search is for finding a single element... I'm not sure how you plan to use it for finding multiple items... You can just iterate the list and do `res = [string for string in input_list if string[0] == input_letter]`

Comment: Oh, it's pity. But ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Also, binary search requires a *sorted* data structure. Your input is an arbitrary list; nothing guarantees that values with indices less than `mid` are actually smaller than `data[mid]`. You can take advantage of properly sorted list to quickly find the *endpoints* of the range you want to return, but sorting takes O(n lg n), while the filter operation you want is only O(n). Maintaining a sorted data structure makes sense when you have a lot of queries that can take advantage of the time spent sorting.

Comment: Yes, I know that. In program I give to my function sorted list of strings